# How to bind text property only if field is disabled in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, binding

I have a form with 2 fields (field1, field2), and a checkbox.

I need the text in the second field to be editable if the checkbox is selected, otherwise, the text in field 2 should be the same as the text in field 1. 
How can I manage this using binding to define them in initialize method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this solely with bindings, because you need to unbind the text in the second text field if the check box is deselected. (Else you will get exceptions when the user types in the text field.)

You can do something like this:

```
field2.editableProperty().bind(checkBox.selectedProperty());
checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
    if (isNowSelected) {
        field2.textProperty().unbind();
    } else {
        field2.textProperty().bind(field1.textProperty());
    }
});
```

If the check box is initially unchecked, you will need an additional call to

```
field2.textProperty().bind(field1.textProperty());
```

to make sure the text field is also initially bound.

Comment: Wonderful! Totally solved my issue! Thank You for the quick response!